# Windows: run an executable from under specific user in domain, passing credentials over http

Tags: python, windows, dns, runas

In our internal network we have a frontend server, running on flask on a windows machine in cloud foundry.
Flask is running under a service user account.

A window domain user connects to the frontend. There are ways to authenticate user on the cloud foundry, so we know his windows domain username (using WSSO).

Task: we need to run a process (executable file) on frontend machine from under the windows domain username, that is connected to web server. How to pass windows authentification from user on remote machine to the frontend?

Note, windows passwords are disabled, windows user is authenticated by an RFID card and pin on his machine.

I was conceiving to run a python subprocess  `runas /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME file.exe`. But how to pass windows domain authentification over HTTP?

Comment: WSSO, workstation single sign-on? Can you be more specific about the exact technology?

Comment: I had a quick look around, but it doesn't appear to be trivial. It looks like what you're looking for is 'SPNEGO' on Flask though. I'd recommend searching a bit with those terms, see if you can find a promising library or framework, try to get it to work and come back here with a code example of what you tried to get more specific advice.

Comment: @GrismarYes, WSSO is a single sign-on. We have an internal service available for Cloud Foundry, that would identify the web client' windows domain username.

Comment: @Grismar, but conceptually, is that how it suppose to work:
I request a hash of remote user windows identity authentication and apply this somehow to `runas` from flask?